# Encontrar o maior e menor elemento de uma matriz

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
def processa(matriz):
    print('----- Matriz Lida -----')
    for i in range(len(matriz)):
        for j in range(len(matriz[0])):
            print(matriz[i][j].center(6), end=' ')
        print()
    return


def localizaCelulaComMaiorValor(matriz):
    resp = (0, 0)
    for lin in range(len(matriz)):
        for col in range(len(matriz[lin])):
            if matriz[lin][col] > matriz[resp[0]][resp[1]]:
                menor = matriz[lin][col]
                resp = (lin, col)
    print('-----------------------')
    print('Maior valor: ', menor, 'na posição: ', resp)
    return


def localizaCelulaComMenorValor(matriz):
    resp = (0, 0)
    for lin in range(len(matriz)):
        for col in range(len(matriz[lin])):
            if matriz[lin][col] < matriz[resp[0]][resp[1]]:
                maior = matriz[lin][col]
                resp = (lin, col)
    print('Menor valor: ', maior, 'na posição: ', resp)
    return

matriz =[]
condicao = 0

while condicao == 0:
  a = input().split()
  matriz.append(a)
  if not a:
    if not a and len(matriz) == 1:
      print('----- Matriz Lida -----')
      print('Matriz vazia, não existem valores')
      print('menor e maior!!!')
      exit()
    matriz.pop()
    processa(matriz)
    localizaCelulaComMaiorValor(matriz)
    localizaCelulaComMenorValor(matriz)
    exit()
```

Quando não digito nada, a mensagem exibida é:

```
----- Matriz Lida ----  
Matriz vazia, não existem valores menor e maior!!!.
```

Está correto.

---

Ao digitar o exemplo de matriz:

```
132 232 

342 4 

222 234 

1232 13
```

A mensagem exibida é:

```
----- Matriz Lida ----  
   132    232     
   342     4      
   222    234     
   1232    13   
   Maior valor:  4 na posição:  (1, 1) 
   Menor valor:  1232 na posição:  (3, 0)
```

Também está correto.

---

Ao digitar o exemplo de matriz:

```
8 5 6 7

13 -4 5 55 

2 3 300 2 

10 2 4 8
```

A mensagem exibida é:

```
----- Matriz Lida ----  
   8 5 6 7     
   13 -4 5 55      
   2 3 300 2
   10 2 4 8


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LOCALIZAÇÃO_FILE", line 46, in <module>
    localizaCelulaComMaiorValor(matriz)
  File "LOCALIZAÇÃO_FILE", line 18, in localizaCelulaComMaiorValor
    print('Maior valor: ', menor, 'na posição: ', resp)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'menor' referenced before assignment
```

Onde estou errando para exemplos como esse, já que o primeiro exemplo funciona? No segundo exemplo só está funcionando a exibição da matriz resultante, não exibe o maior/menor número e sua localização. Como corrigir?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O seu erro está em salvar os inputs do tipo `str` na matriz e querer compará-los como se fossem do tipo `int` depois. O valor `'13'`, por exemplo, não é maior que `'8'`, apesar de que `13` é maior do que `8`. Foi sorte ter rodado das outras vezes.

Bom, para corrigir isso no seu código sem modificar muito, você pode trocar isso `matriz.append(a)` por isso `matriz.append([int(entrada) for entrada in a])`, para transformar sua entrada em inteiros.

E trocar isso `print(matriz[i][j].center(6), end=' ')` por isso `print(str(matriz[i][j]).center(6), end=' ')`, porque você usa o atributo `.center`, que só existe para objetos do tipo `string`.

Além disso, como foi dado o toque pelo @hkotsubo, quando a primeira posição da matriz for o maior, as variáveis `maior` e `menor` também ficarão sem definição. Nesse caso, temos que iniciá-las antes de entrar no for: `maior = matriz[0][0]` e `menor = matriz[0][0]`.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
def processa(matriz):
    print('----- Matriz Lida -----')
    for i in range(len(matriz)):
        for j in range(len(matriz[0])):
            print(str(matriz[i][j]).center(6), end=' ')
        print()
    return


def localizaCelulaComMaiorValor(matriz):
    resp = (0, 0)
    maior = matriz[0][0]
    for lin in range(len(matriz)):
        for col in range(len(matriz[lin])):
            if matriz[lin][col] > matriz[resp[0]][resp[1]]:
                maior = matriz[lin][col] # troquei o nome da variável para ficar coerente
                resp = (lin, col)
    print('-----------------------')
    print('Maior valor: ', maior, 'na posição: ', resp)
    return


def localizaCelulaComMenorValor(matriz):
    resp = (0, 0)
    menor = matriz[0][0]
    for lin in range(len(matriz)):
        for col in range(len(matriz[lin])):
            if matriz[lin][col] < matriz[resp[0]][resp[1]]:
                menor = matriz[lin][col] # troquei o nome da variável para ficar coerente
                resp = (lin, col) 
    print('Menor valor: ', menor, 'na posição: ', resp)
    return

matriz =[]
condicao = 0

while condicao == 0:
  a = input().split()
  matriz.append([int(entrada) for entrada in a])
  if not a:
    if not a and len(matriz) == 1:
      print('----- Matriz Lida -----')
      print('Matriz vazia, não existem valores')
      print('menor e maior!!!')
      exit()
    matriz.pop()
    processa(matriz)
    localizaCelulaComMaiorValor(matriz)
    localizaCelulaComMenorValor(matriz)
    exit()
```

Answer (score 3):

No seu algoritmo para verificar o maior valor, você começa com a primeira posição da matriz:

```
resp = (0, 0)
```

Em seguida, dentro dos *loops* você faz a comparação:

```
if matriz[lin][col] > matriz[resp[0]][resp[1]]:
    menor = matriz[lin][col]
    resp = (lin, col)
```

Mas o que acontece se o elemento na posição (0, 0) for o maior de todos?

Nesse caso, nunca entrará no `if` (pois nenhum elemento da matriz será maior que o primeiro), e portanto a variável `menor` nunca será inicializada. E ao tentar imprimi-la fora do `if`, ocorre o `UnboundLocalError` (já que você tentou imprimir uma variável que não foi inicializada).

A solução é inicializá-la com algum valor inicial antes do *loop*. Como você já está inicializando a posição inicial com `(0, 0)`, pode inicializar a variável com o respectivo valor.

Eu também sugiro mudar o nome para `maior`, já que você está buscando o maior elemento. Nomes melhores ajudam a pensar melhor sobre o problema.

Outra sugestão é usar [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) para percorrer a matriz, pois assim você tem ao mesmo tempo o índice e o respectivo elemento. E como sua função não está retornando nenhum valor, pode até tirar o `return` do final.

```
def localiza_celula_com_maior_valor(matriz):
    resp = (0, 0)
    # maior valor começa com o primeiro elemento
    maior = matriz[0][0]
    for indice_linha, linha in enumerate(matriz): # cada elemento da matriz é uma "linha" (na verdade é uma lista)
        for indice_coluna, numero in enumerate(linha): # cada elemento da linha é um número
            if numero > maior:
                maior = numero
                resp = (indice_linha, indice_coluna)
    print('-----------------------')
    print('Maior valor: ', maior, 'na posição: ', resp)
```

*Claro que, ao inicializar `maior` com o primeiro elemento, a primeira iteração do loop será redundante, pois irá comparar o elemento com ele mesmo. Não é o "cúmulo da ineficiência", mas se isso te incomoda, pode inicializar a variável com um valor bem pequeno (como `-1000000`, por exemplo, ou o [menor valor possível](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7604966) para um inteiro, pois aí "qualquer" valor da matriz será maior que ele).*

---

O mesmo vale para achar o menor valor:

```
def localiza_celula_com_menor_valor(matriz):
    resp = (0, 0)
    menor = matriz[0][0]
    for indice_linha, linha in enumerate(matriz):
        for indice_coluna, numero in enumerate(linha):
            if numero < menor:
                menor = numero
                resp = (indice_linha, indice_coluna)
    print('-----------------------')
    print('Menor valor: ', menor, 'na posição: ', resp)
```

Em também inicializei `menor` com o primeiro elemento, tornando a primeira iteração do *loop* redundante, mas se quiser, também pode inicializar com [o maior valor possível](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7604966) para um inteiro, garantindo que qualquer elemento da matriz será menor que ele.

---

Sobre a leitura da matriz em si, use `matriz.append([int(entrada) for entrada in a])`, como sugerido e explicado na [resposta do Rafael](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/364187/112052).

Já para imprimir, você pode usar [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) com um [`^`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) no formato, que serve para centralizar os números. Repare também que você não precisa dos índices para obter os elementos, já que você não está imprimindo os índices:

```
def processa(matriz):
    print('----- Matriz Lida -----')
    for linha in matriz:  # cada elemento da matriz é uma "linha" (na verdade é uma lista)
        for numero in linha:  # cada elemento da linha é um número
            print('{:^6}'.format(numero), end = '')
        print()
```